# eigenvectors of a sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix. There are a lot of good methods, but this matrix is sparse (>80% zero entries) and diagonal dominant (largest values on diagonal, most non-zero value near the diagonal). All of the diagonal elements have the same value. I also don't strictly need all the eigenvectors, but I do need more than just a few (probably, I need 2,000 out of 40,000). Are there any methods that take advantage of this matrix's structure?

Comment: check out method using Krylov spaces I only have reference in French: Méthodes matricielles - Introduction à la complexité algébrique

Comment: Usually, the quest for eigenvectors comes second after having an idea of the eigenvalues and the way they decrease (because they are real). Look first for (an approximation of) the dominant eigenvalue/eigenvector (obtained e.g. by iterated power method).